# Combining multiple types of Lists into one iterable

Tags: c#

I have a list for each type of object in my game, which all inherit `GameObject`.

```
        public class Registry
        {
            public List<Ball> Balls = new List<Ball>();
            public List<Enemy> Enemies = new List<Enemy>();
            public List<PowerUp> PowerUps = new List<PowerUp>();
            public List<Button> Buttons = new List<Button>();

            // How can I condense this part?
            public IEnumerable<GameObject> AllObjects()
            {
                foreach (Ball ball in Balls.ToArray())
                {
                    yield return ball;
                }
                foreach (Enemy enemy in Enemies.ToArray())
                {
                    yield return enemy;
                }
                foreach (PowerUp powerUp in PowerUps.ToArray())
                {
                    yield return powerUp;
                }
                foreach (Button button in Buttons.ToArray())
                {
                    yield return button;
                }
            }
        }
```

This code works and meets the following requirements:

- I can loop over an individual type of object
- I can loop over all types of objects at once
- I can modify the original list's contents while iterating over it (currently copies the lists with `toArray()`)

I would like to know a way to condense this so I do not need an additional `foreach` loop for every new type I implement.

Comment: At this moment you have effective and extensible way of iteration through all objects. I don't see that adding extra `foreach` loop for every new list can be a big issue, because you already modifying the code by adding new list property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to have only one list of `GameObject`, and use Linq extension methods to filter by type (or even other criteria).

For example:

```
var objects = new List<GameObject>() {
    new Ball(),
    new Enemy(),
    new PowerUp(),
    new Button()
};

var balls = objects.OfType<Ball>();
var enemies = objects.OfType<Enemy>();
var powerUps = objects.OfType<PowerUp>();
var buttons = objects.OfType<Button>();
```

Another option, if you don't want to change your abstractions, is to use Linq [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0) method.

```
public IEnumerable<GameObject> AllObjects()
    => Balls.AsEnumerable<GameObject>().Concat(Enemies).Concat(PowerUps).Concat(Buttons);
```

If you plan to have a lot of individual type-specific lists to join, you can maintain a master dictionary that maps a type to the corresponding type-specific list. Then, you can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) to join them.

```
var master = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<GameObject>> { 
    { typeof(Ball), balls }, 
    { typeof(Enemy), enemies }, 
    { typeof(PowerUp), powerUps }, 
    { typeof(Button), buttons }
};
var all = master.SelectMany(x => x.Value);
```